# Find units of $\mathbb{R}[x] / \langle x^2-3x+2\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I got stuck solving this problem.
First of all, I started with 'simplifying' the quotient ring:
$\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2-3x+2\rangle = \{f(x) + \langle x^2-3x+2\rangle \mid f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]\} = \{ax + b + \langle x^2-3x+2\rangle \mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$

I know that unit is defined as follows:
Element $x \in R$ is a unit iff $\exists y \in R: x*y = 1_R$

So $1_R$ in this quotient ring is: $1+\langle x^2-3x+2\rangle$

Then, according to the definition, I need to find $A = ax+b+\langle x^2-3x+2\rangle$ ($a,b \in \mathbb{R}$) such that there exists $B = cx+d+\langle x^2-3x+2\rangle$ ($c,d \in \mathbb{R}$) for which $A*B = acx^2+bcx+adx+bd+\langle x^2-3x+2\rangle = 1+\langle x^2-3x+2\rangle$

I also found a rule which says: If $R$ is a domain, then units of $R[x]$ are the units of $R$.

$\mathbb{R}$ is an integral domain, so can I use the above statement in this problem? Is this method correct?

If yes, can you help me with finding units of $\mathbb{R}$? I get it that for example units of $\mathbb{Z}$ are $1$ and $-1$. I have a problem with $\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that $x^2-3x+2=(x-1)(x-2)$. So $R$ is not a n integral domain.

Comment: And the units of the real numbers are "all nonzero real numbers".

Comment: It is a good idea to write its elements in the form $a(x-1)+b(2-x)$.

Comment: It might help you to recognize that $0_R = \langle x^2 -3x + 2\rangle$, so everywhere you write $\langle x^2 -3x + 2\rangle$, other than in the definition of $R$, you could just write $0_R$ instead. Further, $x^2 + 0_R = 3x -2 + 0_R$, so you can replace $acx^2$ with $3acx-2ac$ in your calculation of $A*B$: $$A*B = (3ac + bc + ad)x + (bd - 2ac) +0_R = 1 + 0_R$$